# Symfony: Logs are not shown in Toolbar

Tags: logging, symfony

I have Symfony 2.8 and Logging is activated. In my app/logs dir is the dev.log file, it works fine.
But the Logs are not shown in my Symfony Toolbar and also when i open the Profiler, the Logs menu point is not activated. Do I have to activate this in a config? Thanks for any help!

My config_dev.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
    default_locale: "%locale%"

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: [!event]
        console:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
            channels: [!event, !doctrine]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type:   firephp
        #    level:  info
        #chromephp:
        #    type:   chromephp
        #    level:  info

assetic:
    use_controller: true

swiftmailer:
#    delivery_address: me@example.com
    disable_delivery: true

my_website:
    environment: "%locale%"
```

Comment: Paste your `config_dev.yml` please.

Comment: @MadDog see my edit please